# Can I edit a Gcal event that was automatically created from an email?

Tags: google-calendar

Example:

[image]

I could not find a way to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to official documentation it looks impossible:

> After your event is added to your calendar, it will continue to be updated with new information. For example, if you get an email confirmation that you changed the time of your dinner reservation, the time will change in Calendar too.
>
> You can't edit the event details yourself, but you can change notification settings, and who can see your event (see below).

Please, see more details by link:
https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018?hl=en